# Validating regression - common and best practice

Tags: regression, references, nonlinear-regression, regularization, automatic-algorithms

Is there a reference setting out a best practice way to validate a regression (such as Lasso, but in general any automated regression), and what is done in practice?

My motivation for the question is that often simpler tests are useful alongside the more rigorous ones, as the simpler tests are easier to communicate to non-statisticians who are often the users of the work.

Let's assume that the regression model is a polynomial function in many predicative variables (certainly more than 2 or 3 - so hard to plot), and than an automated procedure (such as Lasso) chooses the variables/terms in the polynomial.

My current thinking is:

- In sample testing. Usually done as part of the automated regression procedure.
- Out of sample testing. Easy to communicate, but then you've got to somehow choose the out of sample points
- Cross Validation. Automatic selection of the OOS points and assess the sensitivity of the fit caused by the choice of data
- Anything else?

Comment: Note that if the community considers this question too general, I will try to edit it to make it more acceptable / useful

Comment: This book http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/ gives a very good and clear answer to your question in 600+ pages. I am afraid that your question may be too broad to be answerable in a consise way. Could you try to make your question more focused and precise?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will update the question as a reference request.